# how to setup go mod file after clone from github repo?

Tags: go

Okay, here's some backstory so anyone won't misunderstand.

I have a project called backend and use library `github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2 v2.7.6`
I need to make change in the `go-ora/v2/parameter_decode_array.go` because the switch case is somehow not handling some of []driver.value i need. Therefore i need to trace and tweak it.

Then i git clone it to `/home/user/Projects/go-ora`
i received lot of error, and example is like this `could not import github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2 (no required module provides package "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2")`

which is obvious because the go mod is like this

```
module github.com/sijms/go-ora

go 1.14
```

my question is, how do we setup this library in our local machine ? do i need to change only the module name only, or do i need to change the import part manually one by one, or there's an idiom way to do this. Please also keep in mind that library package is not same as usual package, because afaik library does not have main package

this can lead to another question like, is the author use the same mod file ? or else

something to note too, the author has unusual project structure and kinda anti pattern for having go.mod under go.mod

what i'd tried :

1. git clone git@github.com:sijms/go-ora.git
2. modifying go.mod file

```
module go-ora

go 1.14

replace (
    "github.com/sijms/go-ora" => ./
    "github.com/sijms/go-ora/advanced_nego/ntlmssp" => ./advanced_nego/ntlmssp
    "github.com/sijms/go-ora/network" => ./network
    "github.com/sijms/go-ora/network/security" => ./network/security
)
```

import error still persist

best regards

Answer (score 0):

The module you've cloned uses a less common way of tracking versioned branches. In particular, the `v2` module lives in a subdirectory, rather than being managed by git tags.

This means that you're looking at the wrong `go.mod` file. The correct one is in the [`v2` directory](https://github.com/sijms/go-ora/blob/master/v2/go.mod), and is named correctly:

```golang
module github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2

go 1.17
```

So let's walk through the steps you need to take to use your own customized version of this library:

1. In your project, do the git clone as before:

   ```bash
   git clone git@github.com:sijms/go-ora.git
   ```
2. Edit *your* `go.mod` file. There's no need to edit either `go.mod` file from the `go-ora` repo.  Add a `replace` directive as such:

   ```golang
   replace "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2" => "go-ora/v2"
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Following the steps i can link the `go-ora` and `go-ora/v2` module from my projects. But still the `go-ora` project itself has `could not import` error, especially in `advaned_nego` folder where it doesn't contain go.mod file. 

rather than changing the import from file one by one, my current solution is to use `go mod vendor` , edit from the `vendor/github.com/sijms/...` and run with `go run -mod=vendor .`

Comment: You should not be using `go-ora` _and_ `go-ora/v2`.  You should also never edit files in your `vendor` directory (and rarely should you even _have_ a `vendor` directory).

Answer (score -2):

you need to change the module name to full github-path.
`go mod init github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2`